# Crashing onAction of a button

Tags: javafx, crash, data-transfer

I'm writing a java data transmission program with javafx. Everything runs fine, but when i hit the "send"button in Scene 2 on my program (and the receive button in Scene 3) it crashes my program without any error appearing.
This is my controller class for my Scene 2. 
The problem lies probably in function "send()". This is is the code for creating port and transfer file.

```
public class ControllerSc2 {

@FXML
public Button browsebut,sendbut,backbut;

@FXML
public TextField Path;


@FXML
public TextArea info;

public Socket socket;
public String path,name;
public void browseButton() {

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File sf = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(sf != null){
        Path.setText(path = sf.getAbsolutePath());
        info.setText("Name: "+ (name = sf.getName()) +"\n" + "Size: "+ sf.length() +"Bytes \n" +"From Path: "+ sf.getAbsolutePath() +"\n");
    }
    else{
        Path.setPromptText("please choose something!");
        info.setPromptText("No File was chosen!");

    }


}
public void back(){
    Main.ShowScene1();
}
    //NOTE!!!!!!: critical problem in send function
public void send() throws IOException{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);//this is the code making the program listen to connection from a port
    info.setText("Waiting for connection");
    socket = serverSocket.accept();//waiting connection
    info.setText("Connected....");

    /*DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());//
    dout.writeUTF(name);//transfer name */

    //File transferFile = new File(path);
    File transferFile = new File("C:\\Users\\longt\\IdeaProjects\\a.docx");

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) transferFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    bin.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("Sending Files...");
    os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
    os.flush();
    socket.close();
    System.out.println("File transfer complete");
}
```

}
`

Comment: Does the program immediately crash, or does it hang (stops responding and appears to be stuck), and is either manually or automatically aborted after some time?

Comment: oh sorry for the too late reply, i figured out the problem. it was because my program go in a loop when it wait for someone to connect to the port (5000 in my case) and window mistake it as a not responding program. thank you for your time to take a look at my problem.